# Sending AT commands to modem with a c program

Tags: c, modem

I'm trying to make a program to send AT commands to my PCI internal modem.
I tried with the following command:

```
ECHO ATDT0445534567898 > COM3
```

But nothing happens (COM3 is the serial port which is shown when I look for modem properties)

So I developed this program on the old Borland TurboC 3.0 compiler:

```
#include<bios.h>     
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<dos.h>

#define COM1       0
#define COM2       1
#define COM3       2

#define READY 0x100
#define SETTINGS ( 0x80 | 0x02 | 0x00 | 0x00)
/*baud 1200 | 7 data bits | no parity | 1 stop bit*/

void main()
{

int status,i,x=17;
char *atcommand="ATDT0445534567898";

     bioscom(0, SETTINGS, COM3);

     status = bioscom(3, 0, COM3);

      if (status & READY)
      {
      for(i=0;i<x;i++)
       {
         bioscom(1, atcommand[i], COM3);
       }
      }
}
```

Again, nothing happened. Debugging the program, seems like it is really sending characters one by one to that port but
none dialing action is done. I tried with "ATDT0445534567898;" (I mean, an ending ";" of the AT command), but
it did not work.

I want to make it the simplest it can be. I run it on a DOS environment, but it didn't work. 
Dos environment comes from the "cmd" DOS emulation program which comes along with Windows XP.
However I've run the same program in an old MS-DOS OS computer too, with same results.

Actually, as far as I know, AT commands are interpreted entirely by modem, so none software module (of Windows XP Os or
modem driver) should be involved. Therefore, I think that sending directly the corresponding AT commands to the modem
should be enough.

The modem is working fine since the same AT command works perfectly using Hyper-terminal.

So I'd like to know what´s going on.

Comment: I'm concerned about your SETTINGS bit masking,  but my references are just google hits for bioscom.  The last two ORs in the bit mask are no-ops, but probably are not building an invalid bit field.  What's the full status value returned when you get status?

Comment: First of all: whay are you setting 7 bit serial com?

Comment: Should you be terminating the dial command with a `newline`? That's what happens when you send the command with Hyper-terminal? You type `Enter`?

Comment: Erik, LPs and Weather Vane, thanks for your interest on this question. This the info regarding your comments:

Comment: Settings for the sender modem were got from this link: http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_70.html According with this, the READY status is 0x100. Since the condition (a logical "and" operation) "status & READY" becomes true, I assume that COM3 is available. I really think that no matter whether the modem is set at 7 or 8 bits, 'cause I WON´T SEND ANY DATA. What I want is just dialing a number with a non-interactive programm (so I wouldn´t use  HYPERTERMINAL). Actually, no mather if the calling is answered. By now, I just want to hear the dialing tones from the internal modem.

Comment: I will change the number of used bits and I will add ENTER to the string and let's see what happens. 
However I did a test with a DOS version of putty. I did the same what I did with HYPERTERMINAL to acomplish 
the phone call (which was successful); but using putty, after issuing the dialing AT command, a message is
shown informing that there's no dialing tone. It makes me think that the COM3 related to the internal PCI modem
does not behave the same way as a physical serial com port, thus bioscom or outportb wouldn´t work...

Comment: However. the question could be change by this: How do i directly send a bit stream (like an AT command string) to the modem
PCI bus or modem PCI chip, so it can interpret this bit stream (without using driver software)?